# QPushbutton states transition: lacking "pressed" state

Tags: qt, qpushbutton

I've a question about QPushbutton states transition.

I derived a class, say it MyQPushButton, from QPushButton.
For it I set some visual properties through stylesheet:

Qt Code:
Switch view

```
MyQPushButton
{
background-color: transparent;
border-image: url(<InstallationPath>/Resources/Images/Buttons/MyQPushButton_a.png);
}

MyQPushButton:pressed {
background-color: transparent;
border-image: url(<InstallationPath>/Resources/Images/Buttons/MyQPushButton_b.png);
}

MyQPushButton:disabled {
background-color: transparent;
border-image: url(<InstallationPath>/Resources/Images/Buttons/MyQPushButton_d.png);
}

MyQPushButton:checked {
background-color: transparent;
border-image: url(<InstallationPath>/Resources/Images/Buttons/MyQPushButton_c.png);
}
```

To copy to clipboard, switch view to plain text mode

Interacting with a checkable MyQPushButton instance, image "MyQPushButton_b" (pressed state) appears for a while only by clicking on it on unchecked state, during the transition from unchecked to checked.
I would expect to see the same image for a while also by clicking on it on checked state (reverse transition) as in the documentation http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractbutton.html is reported:

"When the user clicks a toggle button to check it, the button is first pressed then released into the checked state. When the user clicks it again (to uncheck it), the button moves first to the pressed state, then to the unchecked state."

Is my interpretation wrong?
Conversely, how could I "force" the pressed state corresponding image to be shown during the checked-unchecked transition?

Thank you!!!

IR

Answer (score 1):

Change `pressed` to `down`. [The `down` property](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractbutton.html#down-prop) covers both pressed and checked states, however, so make sure your stylesheet fully overrides the appearance changes made by `down` (it does already, but this is just an N.B.).

The "pressed" state the documentation refers to is a non-entity referring to the button being "down" but not "checked". This is equivalent to the following:

```
if (button.isDown() && !button.isChecked())
    ...
```

Diving into the code shows this test is used internally with `QPushButton::initStyleOption()`.

Comment: Hi Jon, thank you very much for your hint! By merely replacing "pressed" with "down" in the stylesheet (If I interpreted you well) I don't get an immediate solution to my problem. However I'm sure I can work around your hint...for example by installing an event filter on checkable MyQPushButton instances and checking the isDown() property you suggested! Coming news...

Comment: Since the button is checkable, you might try putting the "down" state *after* "checked" in your CSS. @ilariari

Comment: No way also introducing a new CSS item: MyQPushButton:checked[down = "true"] {...<image for pressed state> }

Comment: @ilariari I meant moving the "down" style block to after the "checked" style block.